# Where does this go?

Tags: engine, honda, civic, vtec

[image]

I was replacing the head gasket on my 1998 Honda Civic ex it has a d16y8 SOHC VTEC engine. I am stumped on where this little piece goes. It’s not a head pin or anything like that. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! At a glance, it looks like it might be a lock pin for one of the VTEC rocker arms.

Comment: this looks like a valve lifter cap. Did you replace the lifters when you had the heads off?